# Estimate dimensions of objects in video and display them as overlays

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to develop an application to measure the dimensions of an object in video and overlay them in the same video (e.g.h eight and width).  Similar to what is done in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3AxsV8rjos):

[image]

The code I am using:

```
> Andoid MAin Activity

    package com.example.nimesh.opencv;

    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
    import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
    import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
    import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
    import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
    import org.opencv.core.Core;
    import org.opencv.core.CvType;
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
    import android.hardware.Camera.Size;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2,View.OnTouchListener{

        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private MenuItem               mItemPreviewRGBA;
        //private MenuItem               mItemPreviewGray;
        //private MenuItem               mItemPreviewCanny;
        private MenuItem                mItemPreviewFeatures;
        private MenuItem                mItemPreviewComputeMetric;
        private File mCascadeFile;
    //    private camSet mOpenCvCameraView;
        private CameraBridgeViewBase mJavaCameraView;

        private BaseLoaderCallback mBaseLoaderCallback=new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status){
                    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG,"OpencvLoader Successfull");
                        System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");
                        mJavaCameraView.enableView();
                        mJavaCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        static {
            if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
                Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
            mItemPreviewRGBA = menu.add("Preview RGBA");
            // mItemPreviewGray = menu.add("Preview GRAY");
            // mItemPreviewCanny = menu.add("Canny");
            mItemPreviewComputeMetric = menu.add("Compute metric");
            mItemPreviewFeatures = menu.add("Find features");

            return true;
        }

        public void onresume()
        {

            super.onresume();
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0/>,this,mBaseLoaderCallback);
        }

        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mJavaCameraView!=null)
            {
                mJavaCameraView.disableView();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mJavaCameraView=(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.MainActivityCameraView);
            mJavaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            mJavaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        }
        Mat mRgba,mRgbaF,mRgbaT;

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
            mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
            mRgbaF = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
            mRgbaT = new Mat(width, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);  // NOTE width,width is NOT a typo

        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        }

        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
            return mRgba;
        }

        private Mat                    pTs;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
            Log.i(TAG,"Here");
            float x=event.getX();
            float y=event.getY();

            txt.setText("X:"+Float.toString(x)+'-'+"Y:"+Float.toString(y));
            System.out.println(event.getX());
            System.out.println(event.getY());
            Mat a = new Mat(1, 2, CvType.CV_64F); // A matrix with 1 row and 3 columns
            a.put(0, 0, event.getX()); // Set row 1 , column 1
            a.put(0, 1, event.getY()); // Set row 1 , column 2

            System.out.println("ok1");
            if (pTs.empty()){
                pTs=a.clone();
            }else{
                pTs.push_back(a);
            }
            System.out.println("ok2");
            if(pTs.rows()<=2)
               // drawPts(pTs.getNativeObjAddr(),mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
            System.out.println("ok3");



            try{
    //            Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
    //            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    //            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    //            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
    //                    "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
    //            mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
    //            Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw  ex;
            }

            return false;
        }



        //public native void drawPts(long matAddrPts, long matAddrRgba);
    }

> Activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nimesh.opencv.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/MainActivityCameraView"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <!--<Button-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="Capture"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/button"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: im new to this open cv I want develop this full application like i give url VIdeo

Comment: That's not a question. This is a Q&A site. You need to ask a specific question, and provide details of the problems you're having. We don't do tutorials here.

Comment: onTouch function i touch 2 point and i want to  drow line with connet 2 dot

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your question.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve it, but you still need to show the results that you are getting for the code you have shown.  That is, you need to show "what you have tried", as @MikeM. has also indicated.

Comment: The code for the app in the video is available at: https://github.com/suriyasingh/DimensionsApp.  Have you tried it? What are the results you are getting?

Comment: i try it but some features are not in there, and this is eclipse project, i try to build android studio

Comment: If you are having problems importing an Eclipse project into Android Studio, then you should ask a question about that first.

Comment: no its ok i config it.some method are missing